# how can I get registered micro services by using netflix-eureka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-actuator

I registered many microservices using Netflix's Eureka, and also I'm using Spring Cloud Config. However, when I updated the `application.properties` I need to restart the application for the new properties to be applied.

Restarting the application is kind of annoying, so googled it and found that get registered microservices by using Netflix Eureka and refresh it using spring boot actuator, but I have failed to get registered microservices.

In short: How can I get registered microservices using Netflix Eureka?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.When you say "How can I get registered microservices using Netflix Eureka?" do you mean "How can I get the list of services registered to Eureka"?

Comment: sorry I can't speak english well
what I wanna say is "How can I get the list of services registered to Eureka"

Comment: Why do you need to change the application.properties for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access Eureka's registry programmatically using the `com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient` interface.

For example, to send a refresh to all instances of some service:

```
@RestController
public class EurekaOperationsController {
  @Autowired
  private EurekaClient eurekaClient;
  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @PostMapping("/{serviceName}")
  public void refreshAllInstancesOf(@RequestParam String serviceName) {
    Application application = eurekaClient.getApplications().getRegisteredApplications(serviceName);
    application.getInstances().forEach(instanceInfo -> {
      restTemplate.postForEntity(instanceInfo.getHomePageUrl() + "actuator/refresh", null, Void.class);
    });
  }
}
```

And this can be inside any Eureka client, including Eureka service itself since it should be self registered as a client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use eureka to identify service locations then I would highly suggest you to use ribbon on your client side. So you won't need to do any other changes on your application. Please take a look at this one.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html